# Identifying the last time customers ordered a particular item and have them enter a workflow

Tags: workflow, netsuite, saved-searches

I have made a Customer search that identifying the customers that haven't purchased an item in six months or more. I've used  group summaries and maximum summaries for the company name and the maximum transaction date, which refers to the latest sales order containing a certain item. The idea is to send them an email. However, the workflow is only executing on 20 records at a time. i even conducted a search that was not summarized and the workflow still only executed on 20 records. I did use the "Execute Now" button in testing mode to see how many entered the work flow from the summary search. But each execution only yields 20 workflow instances. the searches yield about 213 and 300 records respectively. I appreciate any insight!

Answer (score 2):

Workflows using searches will only process 20 records when in testing mode.

Answer (score 2):

From [SuiteAnswers Article 36738](https://netsuite.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/36738) (NetSuite Login required)

> When you execute a workflow on demand, NetSuite only processes the first 20 records returned by the saved search. For example, if the saved search for a scheduled workflow returns 1000 records, the workflow only initiates on the first 20 records returned by the saved search.